# Why spring data rest maintains arbitrary order of inherited entities

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am facing a challenge with spring data rest where sorting only applies to instances within entity implementations, not across whole result set.

**Entities:**

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "Entity_Type")
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Identifiable<Long> {
    public Long getId();

    @ManyToOne
    RelatedEntity related;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Entity1")
public class Entity1 extends BaseEntity { }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Entity2")
public class Entity2 extends BaseEntity { }
```

**Repositories:**

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractEntityRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, Long> {
   List<T> findByRelatedEntityId(@Param("id") Long id, Sort sort);
}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface BaseEntityRepository extends AbstractEntityRepository<BaseEntity> { }

+ repository for each "T extends BaseEntity"
```

**Now the problem:**

search method `baseEntityRepository/search/findByRelatedEntity?id=...` **with** specified `&sort=id,asc` or `&sort=id,desc` correctly orders the entities within the entity "groups" but the order of the entity "groups" is presented in arbitrary fashion. The arbitrary order seems to be different for `findAll` but it's difficult to confirm without knowing what exactly is going on. Example output:

**Examples:**

sort=id,asc

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "entity1s": [ "id": 1... ],
        "entity2s": [ "id": 3... ],
        "entity3s": [ "id": 2,10,20,... ],   <--- illustrates order is correct within group
        "entity4s": [ "id": 4... ]
   }
}
```

sort=id,desc

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "entity4s": [ "id": 4... ],
        "entity1s": [ "id": 1... ],
        "entity3s": [ "id": 20,10,2... ],  <--- illustrates order is correct within group
        "entity2s": [ "id": 3] 
   }
}
```

**Questions:**

1 - How are the "groups" called in spring data rest?

2 - What is the cause of the arbitrary order? Why doesn't `entity3s` (lowest ID = 2) come before `entity2s` (lowest ID = 3) in the first example?

3 - Can I get entities sorted purely by ID, even if it mixed up the entities?

4 - For `findAll`, why is the result different for paginated output (first 20 records) and full output? (`&size=1000`)